# How do you check if someone faked the last modified date or not?

Tags: file-upload, microsoft, office

I think one of my students faked the modified date of his word file. He's last modified date was exactly the deadline of 13:00:00 (even the seconds are zero). How do i figure this out?? I want to know if he's lying or not.

Comment: There are tools and scripts. https://www.google.com/search?q=modify+file+creation+date You would have to perform a forensic analysis to look for clues in the file. But since you are getting a copy of the file, all the data from the student's file system is not available.

Comment: Don't base dead lines on metadata in the file. Base it on when *you* receive it. You made a poor choice here, and should give your student the benefit of doubt, given that you set the rules.

Comment: You cannot prevent modification of file attributes. Use timestamp service. Before submitting file students should generate its hash, e.g. SHA512, put it to a file, upload it to some timestamp service like OpenTimestamps or TrueTimeStamp. Saving hash to a file and uploading it instead of the original file is needed because we should not trust these services. Students submit a pair of files: the document and the file with a hash. You upload hash file to the same time stamp service and see the timestamp when the student has generated it. Thus this question is well on-topic and I would reopen it.